# Removing rows with 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am working with tables and I want to remove all rows that have 0s on them. I coded the following for table to do so.

```
// eliminating null elements
var k= 0;
for (var i =0; i<operations_row;i++){
    if (Total_Ocurrances[i]!=0) {
        Cause_code_final[k]= Cause_Row_Operations[i];
        Des_final[k]= Description[i];
        Total_DT_final[k]= Total_DT[i];
        Total_O_final[k]= Total_Ocurrances[i];
    k= k +1;



    }
}
```

The variables are all in number format. this is supposed to save a new value into each column every time there is no 0 on the occurrences row, for some reason not all 0s get taken out and some non-0 elements get lost as well.

Comment: Why do you not use `jquery` for this. using simply `.remove` method does your task

Comment: What is operations_row - I think we're missing some info. : )

Comment: You are not really working with tables: you are working with at least 9 separate arrays of which you expect that elements at the same index belong to each other. This is a bad data structure. Use objects in *one* array instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your entire code, but I believe that if possible you should work with objects and use the filter method in your array.

```
var arr = [
    {
        Total_Ocurrances=1,
        Cause_code_final=10,
        Des_final='asdfasf',
        Total_DT_final=new Date(some_value),
        Total_O_final=100
    },
    {
        Total_Ocurrances=0,
        Cause_code_final=12,
        Des_final='qwerqwer',
        Total_DT_final=new Date(another_value),
        Total_O_final=1002
    }
]

var finalArr = arr.filter((item) => {
    return item.Total_Ocurrances != 0;
});
```